# Handling date text input in italian format on Rails 3.0.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, date-formatting

I've a Rails 3.0.7 application that handles many date "text field inputs" in italian format `(%d/%m/%Y)`.

On my Linux Box (configured with italian locale) I run the application and insert into the text box the date 12 november 2014 with an italian format:

```
12/11/2014 (%d/%m/%Y)
```

here Rails correctly saves the date without any problem, same thing if I try to insert a date like 27 november 2014:

```
27/11/2014 (%d/%m/%Y)
```

On the remote production server the date is wrongly saved swapping day and month parts, so my input:

```
12/11/2014
```

is wrongly saved into date:

```
11/12/2014
```

and the date input:

```
27/11/2014
```

raise an exception because 27 is not a valid month...

I suppose that into production server the problem would be that the date format system setting is wrong (`mm/dd/yyyy` perhaps...) but the server is administered by a plesk panel and I don't see anything related to date format system setting...

So the question is: what can I configure in Rails (v. 3.0.x) so that I can save the text field date input in italian format ? (possibly avoiding to write a gazillion of code...)

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: Why not use `date_field` instead of a `text_field`? And if you really want to use a text field then I suggest you use some jQuery date picker library like jQuery UJS.

Comment: Thanks, date_field seems supported by Rails starting from v. 4.0.2, I'm maintaining a v. 3.0.7 legacy application, and yes, I'm using formtastic with jquery datepicker...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby 1.8 uses date format conversion %m/%d/%Y, the 1.9 version instead uses date format %d/%m/%Y, so the solution seems to be switching to Ruby 1.9.x...

Example, the date 28th december 2015 is parsed:

```
In Ruby 1.8: Date.parse("28/01/2015")
In Ruby 1.9: Date.parse("01/28/2015")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first step should be setting up the locale:

```
# config/initializers/locale.rb
I18n.default_locale = :it
```

A few options for dealing with input:

## 1. Replace the text inputs with HTML5 date inputs or Javascript "date pickers"

I really recommend this since you can get validations on the cheap and its a good feature.

## 2. Use [Time/Date/DateTime](http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails) .strptime

```
params_with_dates = params.merge({
  "date" => Date.strptime( params["date"], '%d/%m/%Y' )
})

Foo.create(params_with_dates);
```

Additional reading:

- [Date.strptime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime)
- [Rails Internationalization (I18n) API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

Comment: Many thanks... I've about 100 models (and about 100 controllers), each model has about 20 date fields, using this approach I must write a method in each controller with 1 line for every date field (2000 loc...), is there a better solution to avoid to write so many loc ?

Comment: I haven´t tried using `I18n.default_locale` with dates but I believe it should replicate the behaviour you have on your development box.